# c#:how i can get data time in ISO 8601 format not string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get datatime in `ISO 8601` format

I have parameter mydate which is `DateTime` datatype and I need it's value be like this:

```
DateTime mydate=2015-07-06T12:08:27
```

mydate is not `string` it is `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ToString()` with `O` specifier:

```
var iso8601str = dateTime.ToString("O");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.ToString() to achieve this.

```
var output = mydate.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss");
```